# creation of priority queue - c++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, visual-c++-2010

I want to create a general priority queue. yes I know this can be achieved with STL but I still don't have full understand of it and this is why I want to build one myself.
When I say general I mean it in a sense it will act the same for int,string,any class,etc.
I understand that each item in Queue needs to have at least 2 fields :
 1. value
 2. priority
 so I figure that only my value field should be a template but I found out there ain't such an option.
I am a bit lost here about where I should locate the template and how to use it afterward.

edit1:
The 1st 2 comments said my question is too broad so I'll try to narrow it down.
lets say I got this start of my PQ:

```
template <class T>
class Stack
{
public: 
int priority
template <t> value
Stack(s); //Ctor
}
```

this code is how I fought it Should be written but it doesn't compile.
also If I had methods in the class would  I need to write before each implementation of each method :

```
 template<class T>
```

or maybe I can just use :

```
Stack<T>::Stack(int s) //Ctor
```

Comment: `only my value field should be a template but I found out there ain't such an option.` What you found out is wrong. How many template types and how many variables of what template/non-template - type you have is completely independent. Just make one templated variable and one `int`. Anyway, this question is too broad.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a Q/A website.  You need to ask a specific question to get  a good response here.

Comment: @maor A priority queue is usually implemented as a binary [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)). Learn about them.

Comment: tried to make the question more specific guys.
@vsoftco I am trying to build this one here without the STL of c++.
I believe it will be harder for me to implement binary heap myself then to do it on priority stack[less efficient ?sure , but more educating for me then to use a given library without fully understand].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at `std::priority_queue<T, C, P>` you'll see that it takes three template parameters:

1. The value type `T`.
2. The type of the underlying container `C` (defaulted to `std:vector<T>`).
3. A binary predicate `P` defining the priority order on the elements of type `T` (defaulted to `std::less<...>`).

That is, you'd just store whatever you need to store and define the priority using the binary predicate. If you want to store `int` objects with a separate priority you could, e.g., store a `std::pair<int, priority_type>` and provide a binary predicate comparing the `second` element of these pairs.

I do realize that you want to implement the priority queue yourself but I would entirely follow the standard library model (well, I would move the predicate forward and possibly omit the customization of the underlying container).